# Can the Power-Shell tag be renamed to PowerShell?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently the most popular tag for PowerShell questions is [[Power-Shell]](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-shell). There's no reason for this to be hyphenated, the correct usage is PowerShell (camel cased). This would also align with how the tag is used on StackOverflow. Can it be renamed?

Comment: Makes sense. Will wait for a day for what the community thinks, and will take action accordingly :)

Comment: @Dawny33 I can't imagine the community making sense of that hyphen, it was likely introduced as a typo. Anyway, it's 3 days later and the tag hasn't been changed yet ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for bringing to notice.

The merge [has been done](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powershell)